# Good simple Clipboard manager

Tags: software-recommendation, software, utilities

I'm used to using [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/) on windows, and need something similar on my mac mini.

Any Suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think your best choice is :

- [Clipboard Evolved](http://www.machsoftwaredesign.com/clipboard.html)

But you can also use these softwares:

- [JumpCut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/) (Free and open source)
- [Clipmenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) (As [Calavera](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/26/calavera) said :"ClipMenu is nice because it's free")
- [Clyppan](http://www.omh.cc/clyppan/)
- [CuteClip](http://www.cuteclips3.com/)
- [PTHPasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/)

Comment: ClipMenu is nice because it's free :P

Comment: @calavera I add your quote :P

Comment: JumpCut and Clyppan are also free and open source.  But so far for me, only CuteClip has everything I need.

Answer (score 5):

Added to the answer:

- [Maccy](https://maccy.app) (open source - https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy)
- [Clipy](https://clipy-app.com) (open source - https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy)
- [Clip Menu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) (open source - https://github.com/naotaka/ClipMenu)

All the above three are native apps, have search feature, and are really lightweight and fast. I currently use Maccy and before that I had used Clipy which is excellent as well.

---

Old answer:

[Jumpcut](https://github.com/snark/jumpcut) is the pure clipboard app. [Clyppan](http://www.omh.cc/Clyppan-Clipboard-Manager-for-the-Mac/) is no longer free.

If you do not want all the images you copy to sit in clipboard then **Clip Menu** can be ruled out and **Jumpcut** works good.

There's a Jumpcut fork - [Flycut](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut). I do not see any difference from Jumpcut, except that it(Flycut) seems to be in, relatively more, active development.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) and its Powerpack for clipboard history. Aside from the actual keeping of history, you can save snippets that you use often and call them up with a combination of letters and search among recently copied texts. Alfred's interface for this is much nicer than Jumpcut's in my opinion. I haven't tried any of the others. I haven't found any application to be incompatible with Alfred either.

The price of the Powerpack might seem a little steep for just a clipboard history keeper, but Alfred can do so much more. It has become one of my most essential apps, so give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

Two other clipboard managers that have not been mentioned include:

[iClip](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/iclip/)

The simply useful clipboard manager

[Stuf](http://www.theescapers.com/stuf/index.html)

A clipboard manager with a difference, you can copy and paste between different Macs (and PCs!) over your wired or wireless network! Stuf uses DropBox, so can share your clipboard in the office, or anywhere in the world.

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite attached to [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/).

It's simple, yet powerful enough for all my needs. It even supports snippets which are so useful for a programmer like me.

Comment: I recently switched to Mac and was almost sorry because of Ditto. ClipMenu saved the day. It is very similar, but prettier.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already using [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), it has a clipboard manager built in. It's simple, but works just how I would need it to.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the free software **[Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/)** with the clipboard module.

Here's a [tutorial](http://www.macinstruct.com/node/186) on how to use the clipboard module.

[image]