# How can I copy and paste multiple texts?

Tags: macos, copy-paste

I would like to copy several different texts/things at the same time and paste them in any order.

Does anyone know any good Mac OS X software or plugin that can handle multiple copy/paste?

Comment: This should be a [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts). Flagged for mod attention.

Answer (score 15):

Check this: http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/

Cited from the above:

> Jumpcut is an application that provides "clipboard buffering" — that
>   is, access to text that you've cut or copied, even if you've
>   subsequently cut or copied something else. The goal of Jumpcut's
>   interface is to provide quick, natural, intuitive access to your
>   clipboard's history.

Comment: +10 if I could. First thing I install on any new system. Once you start using it you won't be able to live without it.

Comment: only beware with a security, for example when you copy&paste  your super-secret-password to the dating server - your wife can one click-discover it while you're going for the next beer :)

Comment: OK, I'll only give you only +9 on that basis. But yeh - be careful with your copypasta folks.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

Several app launchers also have clipboard history functionality built-in. I personally use [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/), which supports clipboard history for up to 40 items. I previously used [Quicksilver](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/14831/quicksilver) before development ceased - though I understand it's now back in development.

Comment: +1 for LaunchBar. Clipboard management plus so much more.

Comment: yes, the development of Quicksilver is active again and shortly there has been released a new version vor OS X 10.6 and 10.7: http://qsapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

may I add Butler to the lot, http://manytricks.com/butler/

does many more things in fact, but indeed does the multiclip well...

Answer (score 1):

I use [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/) to handle multiple clipboards. It's nice, has lots of features and it's free.

See also this question: [Good simple Clipboard manager](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/good-simple-clipboard-manager)

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [CmdVees](http://cmdvees.wuonm.com) to scratch my own itch. It solves my specific problem with copy/paste. It may fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this one (no installer, just source): http://github.com/sje397/Clint

Very simple, but quite hackable and works on all platforms supported by Qt and you can network it so that you can share the clipboard across multiple computers.

Comment: Tell us more about it and how is it better than other solutions?