# ClipX equivalent for Mac?

Tags: software-recommendation, switching, copy-paste

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Good simple Clipboard manager](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2958/good-simple-clipboard-manager)

[ClipX](http://bluemars.org/clipx/) is a Windows clipboard management application.

The search feature would be incredibly powerful if I could find a suitable equivalent to Clipx on OS X.

I'm currently using Flycut but it's a bit buggy, inteface isn't what I'd prefer and interacts poorly with Eclipse.

Thanks! So curious if something like this exists.

Comment: You might want to describe what clipx does (and specifically what subset of that functionality you need) since many people may know the mac software and not be aware of what you ask.

Comment: The inline searching capability is something I really need, Flycut doesn't offer this.

Answer (score 4):

I searched Alternativeto.net and came up with [these search results:](http://alternativeto.net/software/clipx/?platform=mac&license=free)

### [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/)

[image: Jumpcut]

> Jumpcut is an application that provides "clipboard buffering" — that is, access to text that you've cut or copied, even if you've subsequently cut or copied something else. The goal of Jumpcut's interface is to provide quick, natural, intuitive access to your clipboard's history.

It sits in your menu bar:

[image: Jumpcut menu]

And you can assign a hotkey to bring up a pasting window:

[image]

According to the Flycut website, Flycut is based on Jumpcut. I am currently using it and love it!

### [PTHPasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard)

Pretty close to Jumpcut, with the exception that there is a paid upgrade.

[image: PTHPasteboard]

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) and its Powerpack for clipboard history. Aside from the actual keeping of history, you can save snippets that you use often and call them up with a combination of letters and search among recently copied texts. Alfred's interface for this is much nicer than Jumpcut's in my opinion. I haven't tried any of the others. I haven't found any application to be incompatible with Alfred either.

The price of the Powerpack might seem a little steep for just a clipboard history keeper, but Alfred can do so much more. It has become one of my most essential apps, so give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/). It doesn't only keep the clipboard, but snippets as well.

Comment: I've been using Clipboard History for years now and it's awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I've tried multiple clipboard managers, but none of them are as polished as [Clips](http://clipsapp.com/), a $10 app that saves clipboard history and allows you to organize and view it in a desktop overlay interface like the way dashboard used to be in snow leopard.